# Should we retract badges in case of serial voting by multiple sock puppets?

Tags: discussion, badges, serial-voting, sock-puppets

As far as I know all badges being earned once will be never retracted, e.g. when votes are changed on vote dependent badge like “great answer” etc. But what if the badge was earned by serial voting of unrelated to the badge owner user and when that user(s) is(are) suspended for creating sock puppet accounts. Should the badge be retracted? I think it should. Looking for the community opinions.

Comment: @rene is question still duplicate after my edit?

Comment: I think it is, yes. I don't see how your question adds any new perspective to the "abusive" context that is used in the dupe. What you describe is also abusive.

Comment: @rene serial voting is allowed (no leads to suspension), but reverted by system on the next day. In the same time sockpuppet account is forbidden for voting on the posts when you can't vote anymore. Hence it's main difference.